formula to describe a sine wave with periodically varying amplitude
I am dealing with a signal collected by a linear Hall magnetic field sensor that measures the magnetic field of 8 magnets on a rotor. Due to the slight difference of the magnets, the plot shows repeating pattern of four amplitudes (1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4...). My question is whether there is a formula that could depict such a signal?


Is it a product of two sinusoids, a (higher-frequency) signal being multiplied by a (lower-frequency) amplitude modulation?

Why is this question closed? I thought I have described the background and details. Closing and downvoting doesn't make more detail and clearity.

Your main signal is of the type $A\sin(\omega t+\phi)+B$, meaning that it's varying around $B$ (about $-500$) with an amplitude of about $1500$. As you noticed the amplitude varies slower in time. So let's just write $$A(t)=C+D\sin\left(\frac{\omega}4 t+\chi\right)$$
This means that the amplitude is close to $C$, about $1500$ and varying with an amplitude $D$, about $200$, and a frequency four times smaller. So the final thing is $$\left[C+D\sin\left(\frac{\omega}4 t+\chi\right)\right]\sin(\omega t+\phi)+B$$

Thanks for your answer! Wouldn't product of higher and lower frequency sine wave lead to the amplitude order of 1-2-3-4-3-2-1 rather than the desired 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4?

It will be 1-2-3-2-1 if you have the same phase. If the phase is shifted, you will get different values

Could you please provide an example to demonstrate a sine wave with the amplitude varying by 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...

$B=0$, $C=10$, $\omega=10$, $\phi=\pi/2$. For $D=0$, at integer $t$ values you get all $10$. If $D=1$ and $\chi=\pi/2$ you get $11., 10.,  9., 10., 11., 10.,  9., 10., 11.$, the 1-2-3-2-1 pattern. If $\chi=0.1$ you get $10.1,   10.995,  9.9,    9.005, 10.1,   10.995,  9.9,    9.005, 10.$, which is 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4-1 pattern

Thank you for the example!
